# How can we prove simply that acceleration for every freely falling body is equal to $g$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass, acceleration, free-fall

If I allow two bodies of different masses to fall freely from same height towards the earth, how can I prove that the acceleration produced in both was constant and equal to gravity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do two bodies of different masses fall at the same rate (in the absence of air resistance)?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11321/)

Comment: Philosopher: "_If I allow two bodies [...] of different masses [...] to fall freely from same height towards earth then how can I prove that the acceleration produced in both was constant and equal to gravity._" -- This follows immediately from the very definition of "**equal gravimetric height** with respect to the Earth's surface". So, in case that's what you meant be "_same height towards earth_", then there is the requested proof. (I may still expand this comment into an answer ...)

Comment: OK go on with that

Comment: I think you may need to explain this question. If two things follow the same trajectory then their accelerations are equal by definition. Where's the mystery?

Comment: @Philosopher   to what else can be equal the acceleration than to the gravitational acceleration? Are there other fields action on the objects?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is of a too low level in physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. If you're wondering about how we know that bodies of different masses fall at the same rate *if we ignore other factors like air resistance*, then you might want to take a look at experiments like [these](http://www.wired.com/2014/11/dropping-objects-worlds-largest-vacuum-chamber/).

If you are interested in how we arrive at the conclusion *that the acceleration is equal to gravity*, we can calculate the gravitational acceleration we would expect based on the masses of the earth and the falling bodies and compare that with the experimental result.
More explicitly, ignoring the relative differences in size between the objects, we start by calculating the force $F$ between the earth with mass $m_{\mathrm{earth}}$ and an object with mass $m_{\mathrm{object}}$ as $$F=G\frac{m_{\mathrm{earth}}\,m_{\mathrm{object}}}{r^2}$$, where $G$ is the gravitational constant and $r$ is the distance between the objects. Since $F=m_{\mathrm{object}}\,a$, we can rearrange to $$a=g=G\frac{m_{\mathrm{earth}}}{r^2}$$, where $g$ is now the acceleration the object feels due to earth's gravity.

If you are interested in how we arrive at the conclusion *that the acceleration is constant*, well, we measure the time it takes the objects to fall certain distances and calculate the acceleration from there (it would only be approximately constant for small distances, but certainly as measured by experiments like the one posted above).

Comment: Graumagier: "_how we arrive at the conclusion that the acceleration is equal to gravity, we can calculate the gravitational acceleration we would expect based on the masses of the earth and the falling bodies_" -- Namely: How, explicitly? No mentioning of "_height(s)_" ?? "_and compare that with the experimental result._" -- Accordingly, we'd arrive case by case at conclusions **whether (or not)**; but not necessarily "_at the conclusion **that** [...]_".

Comment: Of course the distance plays a role in determining gravitational attraction, I've added some additional info. And sure, we would do the experiment to check *whether (or not)* we'd arrive at *that* conclusion ;)

Comment: Graumagier: Thanks. With this topic I just can't help caring especially about the "philosophical" rigor ...

Comment: If that topic happens to be science I'm inclined to agree ;)