# About acceleration of gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration, free-fall

By second law of motion, acceleration is produced by applied force on a body.
Then value of acceleration due to gravity would be different for different bodies on Earth, as the gravity force for them is different?

Comment: The force on different bodies is indeed different because it's equal to $mg$ where $m$ is the mass of the body. However to get the acceleration we have to divide by the mass $m$, so the acceleration is always the same value $a = mg/m = g$

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11321/2451 and links therein.

Comment: At a given spot on earth, the force of gravity on an object is proportional to its mass.  But note that the value of `g` varies depending on where you are on earth (or another celestial body).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do two bodies of different masses fall at the same rate (in the absence of air resistance)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11321/)

Comment: If you take distance to be from the two centres of masses, you'll find that more massive objects reach the constant mass first. If you take one mass to be fixed, the falling objects mass doesn't contribute. The acceleration is given by $GM/r^2$ where $M$ is the mass of the fixed object.

Answer (score 3):

No, they're the same. It's true the force of gravity on them is different, but their masses are also different and the acceleration works out to be the same.

$$F_\mathrm{gravity} = mg = ma\ \rightarrow\ g = a\quad \text{(independent of mass)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let me show you how acceleration due to gravity using derived:

$F = G \frac {M_E m}{R ^2}$ where $G$ is the universal gravitational constant, $M_E$ is the mass of the Earth, $m$ is the mass of the body, and $R$ is the distance between the body and the centre of the Earth.

Now, $F = mg$.

So, $mg = G \frac {M_E m}{R ^2}$

Simplifying,

$$g = G \frac {M_E}{R ^2}$$

So, for a body on the earth's surface or even at a height negligible when compared to the earth's radius, the value of acceleration due to gravity $g$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's second law of motion states that $F = ma$.  The gravity for all objects on earth experience the same gravitational acceleration of $9.81\ \mathrm{ms}^{-2}$.  Thus, force acted on an object would be $mg$ (weight), which is mass X gravity.  However, since $F = ma$, and force on an object is $mg$ (weight), $mg = ma$, so acceleration $a =$ gravitational acceleration $g$, of $9.81\ \mathrm{ms}^{-2}$.

> acceleration is produced by applied force on a body

True, so all objects at rest experience the sole and only force of gravity, hence all have a downward acceleration of $9.81\ \mathrm{ms^{-2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

The *force* on a larger body would be greater, but because this body is also greater in mass, its acceleration is the same as every other body on Earth (a = F/m).

The force of gravity on an object is directly related to its mass.  However, an object's acceleration is *inversely* related to its mass.

Example:

Object A is 5 kg.  Let's say the force of gravity on it is 49 N.

F = ma

a = F/m = 49N / 5kg = **9.8N/kg**   (this is Object A's acceleration).

Now let's increase Object A's mass by 2:

Object A is now 10kg, and since force is directly related to mass, force is now 98 N.

F = ma

a = F/m = 98N / 10kg = **9.8N/kg**

As you can see, Object A's acceleration remains constant.  Increasing an object's mass only changes the *force* on an object.  This is why all objects on Earth have the same gravitational acceleration (ignoring air resistance, and assuming they are all an equal distance from Earth's center).

Comment: Minor correction:  gravity is not the same everywhere on earth.

Comment: @Hot Licks Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting the $m$ in Newton's 2nd law:

$$\sum F=ma$$

Yes, some bodies feel a stronger gravitational force, so $\sum F$ is larger. But then they also have a larger mass $m$. Doubling one will double the other. So $a$ doesn't change.

The acceleration $a$ turns out to alway be equal to $a=-9. 82\mathrm{\frac m{s^2}} $. This numerical value is usually given the symbol $g$.

Answer (score 0):

The value of g is same for all object
Because g= GM/r