# Why acceleration due to gravity same for two objects of different masses (neglecting air resistance)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass, acceleration, free-fall

If a feather ball and bowling ball are thrown , both reach the ground at the same time. (*neglecting air resistance)*

The reason given to this is that

> Both the bodies have same acceleration .

My question is: Why the acceleration is constant although the force is directly proportional to mass?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11321/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Here's a different answer.  The rate at which objects fall has nothing to do with the object. It is only concerned with the difference in time dilation (or spacetime dilation) above and below the object.  This is why a 1 meter vertical pole will fall faster than a 10 meter vertical pole.  But if they were horizontal, they would fall at the same rate.  Think of it more like a weather low pressure system than a bowling ball in a trampoline.  It is the difference in "pressure" above and below the object that determines the acceleration and speed of the fall.