# Would a chess board fall faster than the chess pieces?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, drag

So if they were both falling in air, would the chess board fall faster since it's heavier?

Comment: In space? in water? in air? Remember Galileo and the Leaning Tower of Pisa?

Comment: But remember that if it is heavier it takes more force to accelerate so in that sense perhaps it should fall slower. Put on your thinking cap!

Comment: Are you dropping them one at a time? Or are you setting the up the pieces on the board, and then [dropping them all together](https://xkcd.com/chesscoaster/)?

Comment: Which would fall faster in air? A [giant weather balloon](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00513FWQI) weighing more than a kilogram, or a [streamlined tungsten dart](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07JY7X5Y6/) weighing only 24 grams? When you are asking about the [_terminal velocity_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity) of a body falling through air (or, through any other fluid), there's more to consider than just the mass.

Comment: Comment about terminology: A fall with drag/air resistance is by definition not a [free fall](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11321/2451).

Answer (score 1):

Without air, so assuming the only affecting force is gravity, they will fall **exactly equally fast!** This was Galileo Galilei's discovery.

Sure, the heavier object (higher mass $m$) *does* indeed feel a larger downwards gravitational force. We can calculate it as its weight $w$, where $g$ is the gravitational acceleration it falls with:

$$w=mg.$$

But this larger force has a tougher time accelerating the object due to its larger mass. Newton described that these two effects actually turn out to exactly cancel each other out: an object with, say, double the mass feels double the force $w$ from the formula above but it is at the same time also is double as "slow" in speeding up (accelerating, $a$). Newton's 2nd law describes this:

$$\sum F=ma\quad\Leftrightarrow \quad w=ma \quad\Leftrightarrow \quad mg=ma\quad\Leftrightarrow \quad g=a.$$

As is seen mathematically, the mass cancels out of the equation; the mass has no influence on the falling motion! In total it thus falls just as fast (accelerates just as much) as any other object.

All this is the case in ideal no-air scenarios when the only influencing force is gravity (the weight). When other forces interact as well, such as air drag and the force of moving winds, then the total force $\sum F$ in Newton's 2nd law is constituted by more than just $w$, and then the accelerations may differ. In the case of air drag $D$, a typically used formula is:

$$D=\frac12 C_d A \rho v^2,$$

where $A$ is the frontal area, $\rho$ the density of the air, $v$ the falling speed and $C_d$ a drag coefficient that depends on factors such as shape (a parachute has a huge value of $C_d$ compared to something that is smooth and aerodynamic), surface roughness and the like. To figure out whether the chess board or chess pieces fall faster, we must look for differences among their values of these parameters.

Firstly, we realise that the chess board *angle of attack* is important. Depending on how it is angled during the fall, both $A$ and $C_d$ will be quite different depending on such angle. Still, though, for very low-weight chess pieces, I will expect yet other forces such as wind strokes to have higher impact.

The answer cannot be accurately given from a theoretical perspective since it depends on a lot of practical factors in a given scenario. But now we have at least analysed a bit on which factors to look out for in an emperical experiment.