# Is the rate with which an object gains speed when it is dropped dependent?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration

Is the rate with which an object gains speed when it is dropped dependent or independent of the object's weight?
(gravitational force)

Comment: The context matters here. What forces are acting on the object? Gravitational forces (likely); electromagnetic? Are you near the surface of the Earth, or is the object far from the surface of the planet falling toward it?  Is the mass of the object much smaller than the mass of the Earth or appreciable compared to the mass of the Earth? Etc.  Perhaps also explain what your learning context is.  First course in physics? Layperson? Etc.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11321/2451 and links therein.

Comment: But also: [Don't heavier objects actually fall faster because they exert their own gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3534/dont-heavier-objects-actually-fall-faster-because-they-exert-their-own-gravity?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *usually* independent of the object's weight.

Weight is given by $W = mg$, while Newton's second law says $F = ma$. Equating the two, the mass cancels out, and $a = g$. So the acceleration is usually independent of the object's weight.

Of course, there are possible subtle effects (like air resistance) that can change this conclusion.